# How do I use the The Tkinter Menu Widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I don't get how to add the The Tkinter Menu Widget with my code I tried the code on a website but it won't work. It think im just being silly but please help. Just for the record I have looked at other stack overflow solutions but they did't work.

```
import pyautogui
import time
import tkinter as tk


class Coordinates():
    replayBtn = (100,350)
class YourGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        # inherit tkinter's window methods
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
#Enter X field and label ⬇
        tk.Label(self, text="ENTER X:").grid(row=0, column=3)
        self.inputX = tk.Entry(self)
        self.inputX.grid(row=0, column=1)
#Enter Y field and label ⬇
        tk.Label(self, text="ENTER Y:").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.inputY = tk.Entry(self)
        self.inputY.grid(row=0, column=4)
        # Start Button ⬇
        tk.Button(self, text="start", command=self.do_conversion).grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)
        # close button ⬇
        tk.Button(self, text="exit!", command=self.EXITME).grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)


    def EXITME(self):
        exit(0)  # crashed prog so it closes
        # strtoint("crashmE!")

    def do_conversion(self):
        y = self.inputY.get()
        x = self.inputX.get()

        running = True
        try:
            x = int(x)
            y = int(y)
        except:
            print("Invalid point")
            exit(0)
            # strtoint("crashmE!")
        while running:
            pyautogui.click(x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    your_gui = YourGUI()
    your_gui.title('Macro Clicker') # Set title
    your_gui.iconbitmap('favicon.ico') # Set icon
    your_gui.resizable(False, False)
    your_gui.mainloop()
time.sleep(0)
```

Comment: Follow this pattern [The Tkinter Menu Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm)

Comment: Your code doesn't show any attempt at creating a menu widget. Please show what you've tried. There are countless examples on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that but if you aren't lazy u will find over thousend examples about tkinter menu.
Even your code has nothing to do with tkinter.menu!?

Here's an example of mine. The "Info" menu is empty just to show you how create additional menus.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu

class Gui(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        Frame.__init__(self, self.master) #main container
        self.grid()
        self.create_menu()

    def create_menu(self):
        self.menubar = Menu(self.master)
        self.theme = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="View", menu=self.theme)
        self.menubar.add_command(label="Info", command=self.passing)
        self.views = Menu(self.theme, tearoff=0)
        self.theme.add_cascade(label="Themes", menu=self.views)
        self.views.add_command(label="Default", command=self.passing)
        self.views.add_command(label="Red", command=self.passing)
        self.views.add_command(label="Blue", command=self.passing)
        self.views.add_command(label="Random", command=self.passing)
        self.master.configure(menu=self.menubar)

    def passing(self):
        print("Use your brain before asking questions on stackoverflow or use google if your brain is slow")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x200")
    my_gui = Gui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```